# EditText to integer in android

Tags: java, android

i checked this web site on how to convert from string to integer type in java(android).... one of suggestion was to use (integer.parseint) i used it and when i run my application it says my app has stopped working my code below .

```
 public void clickable (View view){
           EditText mytext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Creat);
           int number = Integer.parseInt(mytext.getText().toString());
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
```

i cant figure out what is the problem with the code ?!

Comment: maybe chracter a-z or A-Z in EditText

Comment: @RasoulMiri no not character i checked every character in the code lower case or upper case

Comment: for convert String to Integer , String just contain 1234567890

Comment: Please post the error log. Thank you!

Comment: @RayLi 07-12 23:41:55.628 4083-4083/com.example.mahmoud_elattar.engineering_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           Process: com.example.mahmoud_elattar.engineering_app, PID: 4083

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)

Comment: at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)

Comment: and llots of error

Comment: Please post the error log via https://pastebin.com/ instead of the comments section. It's much easier to read that way ;)

Comment: @RayLi my fault here is the link https://pastebin.com/zXhLXAjh

Answer (score 1):

Declare EditText mytext variable as a global variable and then initialize it in Oncreate() method of your Activity. Then your clickable method looks like this:

```
public void clickable (View view){
       int number = Integer.parseInt(mytext.getText().toString());
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mytext.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Obeserve Toast.makeText() method's second argument is the resource id of the string resource to use or it can be formatted text. In your code you have passed an integer as a resource id which does not exist. So you get ResourcesNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

What string are you passing into the Integer.parseInt()? If it's not an integer, your program will experience a NumberFormatException. I'm not sure if that's the issue here, but I'm not sure what you're passing into the Integer.parseInt().

Comment: i'm passing numbers , is that kind of logic error as i should pass string that be converted to integer or this is not the cas ?!

Comment: How big are your numbers? If they're too big, the program will still experience a NumberFormatException if the numbers are too big to fit in an Integer. What are some of the numbers that you tried to pass in?

Comment: just 55 , 88 and 5 not that big

Comment: Just saw your error log. I'm not sure but I think the problem might be in myText.getText(). Could you check what that returns please? If it's null, then the toString() will cause an IllegalStateException.

Comment: i enter number so it return number ... by the way i made input type  numbers only

Comment: Actually, I just saw your complete error log in the pastebin, and the myText.getText() is probably not the issue. It's a ResourcesNotFoundException, not a NullPointerException. I think the issue might be in your Toast.makeText(). I think you need to enter the integer as a String, so I don't think you need to parse the string into an integer. I think you can just enter the string into that field instead of number.

Answer (score 0):

There are many implementations of `Toast.makeText`. As you are passing an `int` as the second argument, the following implementation will execute:

```
Toast makeText(Context context, @StringRes int resId, @Duration int duration)
```

This implementation will throw a `ResourcesNotFoundException` if it cannot find a resource with the id of `resId`.

To output `number` as a `String` you need to convert it:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(number), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: realy thx man .valueof(number) worked for me :) :) :)....but why parsenint not working ?!?!

Comment: I cannot see a problem with it. Are you sure you are giving it digits from the EditText? Otherwise you will get a NumberFormatException

Comment: You can enforce this by setting this XML attribute to your EditText - android:inputType="number"